# What do you call the period after sunrise when the sky is bright?

Tags: astronomy, soft-question, time, terminology, earth

At sunrise, the sky isn't actually up in the sky yet. Twilight occurs before sunrise, then at sunrise the leading part of the sun crosses the horizon. But, the sky isn't bright yet. It takes some time for the sky to be blue again.

Then, at the closing of the day, the sky darkens before twilight, then sunset.

Basically, there is a narrower time when the sky is bright and blue, rather than being the time between sunrise and evening twilight. Is there a name for these times, or at least a name for its boundaries?

Edit:
Here's a picture to better point out what I mean:

[image]

The shaded part after sunrise I label [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJzEe.png) is the part after sunrise, when the sky is still dark but the sun is out in the sky ([here's an image](http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/582749main_sunrise_from_iss-4x3_946-710.jpg)).

The shaded part just before sunset I label [2](http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/582749main_sunrise_from_iss-4x3_946-710.jpg) is the part when the sky is already darkening, but it's not yet sunset as the sun hasn't set below the horizon ([an image again](http://www.theroamantics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/rarotonga-sunset-1-theroamantics-com.jpg)).

The large portion of the day I label [3](http://www.theroamantics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/rarotonga-sunset-1-theroamantics-com.jpg) would be the part when the sky is blue and bright, the term for which I'm asking for, if it exists ([here's an image](http://pinker.wjh.harvard.edu/photos/cape_cod/images/blue%20sky%20sailboat.jpg)).

Comment: Can you add some pictures?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not seem to be about physics.

Comment: Well, I tried to go to an astronomy-related stack exchange but it was closed, and all the things there were moved to the physics stackexchange, so I figured this is probably the best place to ask.

Comment: After sunrise when the sky is bright? I call it day

Comment: @Dilaton this is the physics **and astronomy** stack exchange. It's on topic.

Comment: @Nathaniel of course we do here astronomy and physics ... :-). I was not thinking it could be off topic because of it beeing an astronomy question, I rather thought it is rather about quite everyday terminology instead of about astrophysics, astronomy, or physics ... So just say leave open, if you think the question is good enough ;-)

Comment: @Dilaton It seemed to me to be a question about astronomical terminology. "Everyday physics" questions are on topic here (and some of them are quite good), so I think "everyday astronomy" ones should be as well :)

Comment: @Nathaniel sure as long as it contains enough anstronomy and/or physics and not just everyday, it should be ok. We even have an everiday-life tag, and life consists of both, astronomy and physics among other things. Yep, some of these questions are fun indeed :-D

Comment: Thanks for sparing it the lock. :) @Jim, unfortunately the beginning and end of a day is midnight, so it covers all 24 hours and doesnt end at twilight/sunrise/sunset.

Comment: @markovchain when referring to the time unit, day, it is the entire 24-hour period. But alternate usages of "day" allow it to mean the period during the 24-h span when the Sun is up. In those usages, the remaining period is referred to as "night". Thus the oft used contrast between night and day, which would be meaningless if day included night.

Comment: @Jim that's definitely a good point. But in that case, the start and end of the day would be the sunrise and sunset respectively. I get what you mean, and in everyday usage there would be no debate as to what you mean, but I'm asking if there's a formal name for that particular time. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about terminology, not physics.

Comment: See [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/25301) about terminology/notation questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is daylight, civil twilight, nautical twilight and astronomical twighlight.   Each defined by the position of the sun relative to the horizon.

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight) seems unusually helpful.  With diagrams as well.

Comment: The twilights happen before sunrise, so basically at the end of the very last twilight, is sunrise. At sunrise, the sky isn't blue or bright yet. The wikipedia article doesnt mention a "boundary" in the day after sunrise when the sky does become blue. Maybe there just isnt a word for it.

Answer (score -1):

The time after the Sunrise is known as Morn.

Comment: Consider including a reference. We like those here! Cheers!